# How to run package.json script from ASP.NET Framework

Tags: c#, angular, typescript, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I want to run an Angular Web app and WebAPI in the same service and to do that I want to run an npm start script from package.json from the .NET Framework code.

The project view: https://i.stack.imgur.com/M86p1.jpg (couldn't post an image due to reputation)

I know it's possible to do from a .NET **Core** code:

```
app.UseSpa(spa =>
            {
                spa.Options.SourcePath = "Angular";

                if (env.IsDevelopment())
                {
                    spa.UseAngularCliServer(npmScript: "start");
                }
            });
```

But the project needs to be a .NET **Framework** one so that I'll be able to use legacy .NET Framework dlls.

Answer (score 2):

You can add this setting in your `csproj` file

```
<Target Name="DebugEnsureNodeEnv" BeforeTargets="Build" Condition=" '$(Configuration)' == 'Debug' And !Exists('$(SpaRoot)node_modules') ">
<!-- Ensure Node.js is installed -->
<Exec Command="npm run something" ContinueOnError="true">// add your npm script here
  <Output TaskParameter="ExitCode" PropertyName="ErrorCode" />
</Exec>
```